# Android: anim.slide_in_right No se puede Encontrar

Tags: android

Tengo el siguiente código pero no puedo acceder a `android.R.anim.slide_in_right`

```
package com.agmdeveloptest.testinganimations;

import android.animation.Animator;
import android.media.Image;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewAnimationUtils;
import android.view.animation.AlphaAnimation;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ViewSwitcher;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button buttonPrev, buttonNext;
    ViewSwitcher viewSwitcher;
    Animation slide_in_left, slide_out_right, lol;

    TextView  txttoAnimate;
    ImageView imageView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buttonPrev = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prev);
        buttonNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
        viewSwitcher = (ViewSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.viewswitcher);

        lol = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                android.R.anim.slide_in_right);
        slide_out_right = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                android.R.anim.slide_in_right);

        viewSwitcher.setInAnimation(slide_in_left);
        viewSwitcher.setOutAnimation(slide_out_right);

        buttonPrev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                viewSwitcher.showPrevious();
            }
        });

        buttonNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                viewSwitcher.showNext();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

el archivo existe, esta en la misma carpeta de `slide_in_left` y este último si puedo invocarlo en  `android.R.anim.slide_in_left`

aqui esta el xml de `slide_in_right` ( es más.. cuando le doy `CTRL+CLICK` me dirije al xml , osea que existe , pero me sale, `cannot resolve symbol 'slide_in_right'`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
/* //device/apps/common/res/anim/slide_in_right.xml
**
** Copyright 2007, The Android Open Source Project
**
** Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); 
** you may not use this file except in compliance with the License. 
** You may obtain a copy of the License at 
**
**     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 
**
** Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software 
** distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, 
** WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. 
** See the License for the specific language governing permissions and 
** limitations under the License.
*/
-->

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="50%p" android:toXDelta="0"
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

Comment: el archivo esta en el proyecto android en Resources/anim ? ósea al mismo nivel de drawable. tienes que tener una carpeta con el nombre anim en resources y meter el archivo ahí. Luego lo llamas con R.anim.slide_in_left

Comment: creo que no me comprendes  R.anim.slide_in_left  si me deja invocarlo, y esta la misma carpeta de slide_inright pero no me deja invocar al right, al igual que un monton de más arhcivos que estan en el mismo nivel de slide_in_left pero no me deja acceder

Comment: Creo que ya te comprendí, son recursos del SDK que no puedes llamar... porque los usas con android.R.anim.XXXXX. y si los copias y los agregas a tu propia carpeta anim los renombras y los llamas R.anim.xxx ósea el anim de tu proyecto? Esto sería una opción

Comment: ya lo intenté y tampoco u_u", y no entiendo que estara mal, hay muchisimas animaciones en esa acarpeta que no me deja invocar

Comment: mm deberia de funcionar, agrega a la pregunta un pantallazo de la estructura del proyecto. Es solo para ver como agregaste el archivo en los recursos. No hace falta que se vean los paquetes solo la parte de recursos.

Comment: ahm, soy algo nuevo y pues en la carpeta Res no se ve ninguno de ellos, se ven es, cambiandoa rriba por pacakages y luego libraries,y luego anim, pero salen cientos de ellas y solo me muestra como 4

Comment: @AndressBlend ya encontré el problema revisa mi actualización, en realidad la animación debe llamarse : android.R.anim.slide_out_right

Comment: pero es que ya uso out_right, quiero usar es in:right, o sea al contrario

Comment: De acuerdo, ya sabemos que quieres usar ....in_right. La carpeta anim no existe por defecto en un proyecto Android, por lo que tienes que crearla justo como en la respuesta de @JorgeSys. La creas y luego agregas el archivo xml de in_right. Ya luego para usarlo lo usas con R.anim....in_right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si es una animación que tu realizaste, debes asegurar que el elemento se encuentre dentro de `res/anim/`

[image: **introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí**]

Esto para que puedas cargar correctamente el recurso, pero lo tienes que realizar de esta forma:

```
lol = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in_right);
```

Si tienes tu recurso y no lo puedes acceder, puedes realizar un "Clean" de tu proyecto para que vuelva a generar las referencias.

---

El problema es que tratas de cargar animaciones del SDK (estas usando `android.R.anim.)`, y `slide_in_right` NO existe, debe ser `slide_out_right` , en este caso el nombre de las animaciones debe ser:

```
android.R.anim.slide_in_left
```

y

```
android.R.anim.slide_out_right
```

Comment: ya le di clean pero no sale la carpeta anim en res :/, y osea que por mas que exista ese slide_in_right no puedo usarlo?

Comment: No es una animación que tu creaste, es una animación del SDK la que tratas de cargar, en este caso solo existe; "android.R.anim.slide_in_left " y "android.R.anim.slide_out_right

Comment: no yo no la cree, pero ya estaba ahi creada, no la puedo usar de alguna forma?

Comment: mira https://i.imgur.com/rfWIBQU.png todas las que hay pero solo me deja usar 2 in_left y out_right :S

Comment: ahhh, revisa mi respuesta si cargas desde el folder, debe ser lol = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in_right); NO USAR android.R.anim.slide_in_right

Comment: Grande !!!!! ohhh osea que cuando uno pone android.R ya es otra carpeta distinta a Res, mil gracias amigo

Comment: android.R  significa que estas tratando de leer un recurso del SDK, un placer ayudarte Andress,, saludos!